# Tkinter program does not work correctly on first try, works as intended after restart

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

The GUI tiles in this program don't work properly when I first launch the program, but they seem to work fine after I hit the restart button. It seems like the issue is with `find_closest()` not selecting the right squares on launch, but it seems to work properly after restarting in the `play()` method.

```
def play(self, event):
    """
    user performs a move
    calls computer move directly after if game not over
    """
    selected_square = self.canvas.find_closest(event.x, event.y)
```

I've tried moving `board` to be an instance variable, but that didn't fix it.

Here is the `__init__` method:

```
class Game(object):
'''
GUI Tic-tac-toe game.

Argument:
parent (tkinter.Tk): the root window object

Attributes:
canvas = (tkinter.Canvas) widget defining game board
game_over = (bool) game state, game over = False, game ongoing = True
moves = (int) number of moves taken by both user and computer
label = (tkinter.Label) shows win/loss/draw message
'''

# Add your class variables if needed here - square size, etc...)
board = [[0, 0, 0],
         [0, 0, 0],
         [0, 0, 0]]

MAX_MOVES = 9

def __init__(self, parent):
    self.parent = parent
    parent.title('Tic Tac Toe')
    # Create the restart button widget
    restart_button = tkinter.Button(self.parent, text='RESTART', width=20,
                                    command=self.restart)
    restart_button.pack()
    # Create a canvas widget

    self.canvas = tkinter.Canvas(parent, background='white', width=300,
                                 height=300)

    self.canvas.create_rectangle(0, 0, 300, 300)
    self.canvas.create_rectangle(0, 0, 100, 100)
    self.canvas.create_rectangle(100, 0, 200, 100)
    self.canvas.create_rectangle(200, 0, 300, 100)

    self.canvas.create_rectangle(0, 100, 100, 200)
    self.canvas.create_rectangle(100, 100, 200, 200)
    self.canvas.create_rectangle(200, 100, 300, 200)

    self.canvas.create_rectangle(0, 200, 100, 300)
    self.canvas.create_rectangle(100, 200, 200, 300)
    self.canvas.create_rectangle(200, 200, 300, 300)

    self.canvas.pack()

    self.label = tkinter.Label(self.parent, text="")
    self.label.pack()

    self.game_over = False
    if not self.game_over:
        self.canvas.bind("<Button-1>", self.play)
    self.moves = 0
```

Here is the restart method:

```
    def restart(self):
    """
    resets game to beginning state

    label erased, game tiles turned back white, button-1 rebound, moves set
    to zero
    """
    for square in self.canvas.find_all():
        self.canvas.itemconfigure(square, fill='white')
    self.board = [[0, 0, 0],
                  [0, 0, 0],
                  [0, 0, 0]]
    self.moves = 0
    self.game_over = False
    self.canvas.bind("<Button-1>", self.play)
    self.label.config(text="")
```

The rest of the code can be found [here](https://gitlab.com/snippets/1787766).

I've tried printing event.x and event.y and it seems like they're registering correctly as well as updating the board correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The canvas/bindings aren't properly configured when the game starts.  I haven't really dug through your code to find out why (There's a lot to dig through for a short answer), but your indices seem to be one behind when you first start.  This can be fixed by adding the canvas configuration loop from your `restart()` function to the game loop at the bottom of the code block as follows:

```
def main():
    root = tkinter.Tk()
    gen_game = Game(root)
    **for square in gen_game.canvas.find_all():**
        **gen_game.canvas.itemconfigure(square, fill='white')**
    root.mainloop()
```

Or by adding it to the bottom of the `__init__` function as follows:

```
def __init__(self, parent):
    self.parent = parent
    parent.title('Tic Tac Toe')


    # Create the restart button widget
    restart_button = tkinter.Button(self.parent, text='RESTART', width=20,
                                    command=self.restart)
    restart_button.pack()
    # Create a canvas widget

    self.canvas = tkinter.Canvas(parent, background='white', width=300,
                                 height=300)

    self.canvas.create_rectangle(0, 0, 300, 300)
    self.canvas.create_rectangle(0, 0, 100, 100)
    self.canvas.create_rectangle(100, 0, 200, 100)
    self.canvas.create_rectangle(200, 0, 300, 100)

    self.canvas.create_rectangle(0, 100, 100, 200)
    self.canvas.create_rectangle(100, 100, 200, 200)
    self.canvas.create_rectangle(200, 100, 300, 200)

    self.canvas.create_rectangle(0, 200, 100, 300)
    self.canvas.create_rectangle(100, 200, 200, 300)
    self.canvas.create_rectangle(200, 200, 300, 300)

    self.canvas.pack()

    self.label = tkinter.Label(self.parent, text="")
    self.label.pack()

    self.game_over = False
    if not self.game_over:
        self.canvas.bind("<Button-1>", self.play)
    self.moves = 0

    **for square in self.canvas.find_all():**
        **self.canvas.itemconfigure(square, fill='white')**
```

Note:  Don't actually include the `**` when you copy the code.  It is just there for emphasis.  If it weren't a code block, that would have been reformatted as bold, but it can't be formatted as both **bold** and `code`.

Comment: That does it! Thanks.